# how to create the following map of map in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am a Scala newbie: how can I create the following "map of map" in Scala:

```
"Outer" map
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
|           Key           |             Value             |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| (employeID, currencyID) | (valueDate, set of CashFlow)  |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

The value in the "outer" map is also a map:

```
"Inner" map
+-----------+------------------+
|    Key    |      Value       |
+-----------+------------------+
| valueDate | set of CashFlow  |
+-----------+------------------+
```

with the following types:

- employeeID: Int
- currencyID: Int
- valueDate: java.util.Date
- set of CashFlow: Set[com.company.CashFlow]

The following won't compile (need to override +=, -=, etc):

```
myMap = new mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), java.util.TreeMap[Date, mutable.Set[CashFlow]] with mutable.MultiMap[Date, CashFlow].withDefaultValue(new util.TreeMap[Date, mutable.Set[CashFlow]] with mutable.MultiMap[Date, CashFlow]
```

Requirements:

- map must be mutable
- sorted by valueDate
- for one valueDate, I can have multiple cash flows
- I would like to avoid checking for key existence on (employeeID, currencyID), i.e. `myMap(emp1, ccy1).addBinding(date1, cashFlow1)` shouldn't fail if the key doesn't exist. 
  Instead, it should automatically create a new empty sorted MultiMap and initialize it with (date1, cashFlow1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create it without `MultiMap`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._, JavaConverters._, java.util.TreeMap

val myMap = new mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), mutable.Map[Date, Set[CashFlow]]]{ 
    override def apply(k: (Int, Int)) = 
       getOrElseUpdate(k, new TreeMap[Date, mutable.Set[CashFlow]].asScala) 
}
myMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),scala.collection.mutable.Map[java.util.Date,scala.collection.mutable.Set[CashFlow]]] = Map()
```

`override def apply` needed as `withDefaultValue` will always return you the same value.

It's also possible to create `MultiMap` from java's `TreeMap` using standard wrappers:

```
import scala.collection.convert.Wrappers._

//This wrapper will hold your Java's TreeMap inside, and delegate all operations to it
scala> def newTreeMultiMap[K, V]: MultiMap[K, V] = new JMapWrapper(new TreeMap[K, Set[V]]) with MultiMap[K, V]
newTreeMultiMap: [K, V]=> scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[K,V]

scala> val myMap = new HashMap[(Int, Int), MultiMap[Int, String]]{ override def apply(k: (Int, Int)) = getOrElseUpdate(k, newTreeMultiMap[Int, String]) }
myMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[java.util.Date,CashFlow]] = Map()
```

I think it should be in standard library but didn't find any.

Examples (I used `Int` instead of `Date` to show that ordering works):

```
scala> val myMap = new HashMap[(Int, Int), MultiMap[Int, String]]{ override def apply(k: (Int, Int)) = getOrElseUpdate(k, newTreeMultiMap[Int, String]) }
myMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String]] = Map()

scala> myMap(0 -> 0).addBinding(4, "aaa") //no exceptions on myMap(0 -> 0) with empty Map
res27: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map(4 -> Set(aaa))

scala> myMap(0 -> 0).addBinding(2, "aaa") //should be before 4
res28: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> Set(aaa), 4 -> Set(aaa))

scala> myMap(0 -> 0).addBinding(5, "aaa") //should be after 4
res29: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> Set(aaa), 4 -> Set(aaa), 5 -> Set(aaa))

scala> myMap(0 -> 0).addBinding(4, "bbb")
res30: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> Set(aaa), 4 -> Set(aaa, bbb), 5 -> Set(aaa))

scala> myMap(0 -> 0).toList //finally use the order
res31: List[(Int, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String])] = List((2,Set(aaa)), (4,Set(aaa, bbb)), (5,Set(aaa)))

scala> myMap(0 -> 1).addBinding(2, "aaa") 
res18: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map(2 -> Set(aaa))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! works perfect using the wrappers solution

Comment: I was too fast in my testing: I don't know if it's a bug, but the same multimap is reused for every (Int, Int) tuple, so it won't work for me. Do you know how to implicitely create a new multimap for each different tuple?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer (see `val myMap =` ) - just override the `apply`  method of your `HashMap` with `override def apply(k: K) = getOrElseUpdate(k, newTreeMultiMap[K, V])` instead of using `withDefaultValue`